# React, javascript findIndex issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

when I get **activeFilters** values like this:

```
const filter = [...activeFilters]
```

findIndex always return -1 even when the item i'm searching exist.

but when I get like this, it works ?

```
const filter = activeFilters
```

did I miss something ?

```
const [activeFilters, setActiveFilters]  = useState([]);

 const handleFilters = async (selectedKeys) => {
    
    const filter = activeFilters
  
    const index = filter.findIndex(array => array.key === selectedKeys.key)
    console.log(index)
    if(index !== -1){
       filter[index] = selectedKeys
    }
    else{
       filter.push(selectedKeys)
    }

    console.log(filter)
    setActiveFilters(filter)
    
}
```

**Edit ****

console.log output on filters after choose two different filters **without spread operator** :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {value: Array(2), key: "sourceCustomer"}
1: {value: Array(1), key: "targetCustomer"}
```

`console.log` output on **with spread operator** after choose two different filters :

```
[{…}]
0: {value: 321123, key: "cost"}
```

it's value is always replaced

Comment: what is selectedKeys.key? is it string or object?

Comment: it's a string... selectedkeys content example : {value: Array(1), key: "targetCustomer"}

Comment: Could you please paste the data you have for active filters ? Because spread operator is used for shallow copy only and may work unexpectedly as nested objects are not actually cloned

Comment: Sure, I'm using ant design and I follow this example to custom filter panel https://codesandbox.io/embed/dvc6s?codemirror=1. The only thing I changed was, instead using selectedKeys and dataIndex on handleSearch function ... I did like : handleSearch({key: dataIndex, value : selected Keys})

Comment: Could you console.log your filters with both approach. They seem to me that they should result in same object.

Comment: I updated my post, I dont know if it's what you wanted.

Comment: Maybe posting your own codesandbox link will help. (Easier than guessing ;))

Comment: You seem to mutate the `filter` const by setting 
```if(index !== -1){
       filter[index] = selectedKeys
    }
    else{
       filter.push(selectedKeys)
    }```
Can you try to avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem adding activeFilters on useEffect second param like :

```
 useEffect(
    function fetchColumns() {
      const result = handleColumns.find(
        (element) => element.key === transactionContext
      );
      return setColumns(result.value);
    },
    [partners, transactionType, partnerScroll, activeFilters]
  );
```

**this way react could see the change on activeFilters.. but I dont know if it is the best way**

example of some of the filter columns:

```
  const columnsInsider = [
    {
      title: "Detalhes wallet",
      align: "center",
      render: (render) => (
        <Button
          handleClick={() => handleDetails(render.transactionWallet.data)}
          icon={<FaRegEye color={softGrey} />}
          backgroundcolor="transparent"
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      title: "Tipo de Transação",
      dataIndex: ["transactionType", "desc"],
      sorter: true,
      key: "orderTransactionType",
      ...getColumnSearchProps(
        "type",
        "select",
        "multiple",
        fetchTransactionTypes,
        transactionType
      ),
    },
    {
      render: (render) =>
        Moment.utc(render.transactionDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"),
      title: "Data",
      key: "orderTransactionDate",
      sorter: true,
      ...getColumnSearchProps("date", "datepicker"),
    },
    {
      title: "Nome origem",
      dataIndex: ["source", "name"],
      sorter: true,
      key: "orderSourceCustomerName",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCnpjCpf(render.source.document.value),
      title: "Documento origem",
      ...getColumnSearchProps("sourceCustomer", "select", "tags"),
    },
    {
      title: "Nome destino",
      dataIndex: ["target", "name"],
      sorter: true,
      key: "orderTargetCustomerName",
    },
    {
      render: (render) => formatCnpjCpf(render.target.document.value),
      title: "Documento destino",
      ...getColumnSearchProps("targetCustomer", "select", "tags"),
    }
]
```

custom panel filter that calls handleFilters:

```
 const getColumnSearchProps = (
    dataIndex,
    filter,
    mode = null,
    fetchOptions = null,
    options = [],
    onScroll
  ) => {
    return {
      filterDropdown: ({
        setSelectedKeys,
        selectedKeys,
        confirm,
        clearFilters,
      }) => (
        <div style={{ padding: "1rem" }}>
          <Filter
            filter={filter}
            mode={mode}
            placeholder={`Pesquisar...`}
            onFocus={fetchOptions}
            onChange={setSelectedKeys}
            onPressEnter={() =>
              handleFilters(
                { value: selectedKeys, key: dataIndex },
                confirm,
                dataIndex
              )
            }
            options={options}
            onPopupScroll={onScroll}
            handleFilter={() =>
              handleFilters(
                { value: selectedKeys, key: dataIndex },
                confirm,
                dataIndex
              )
            }
            handleClear={() => handleClearFilters(clearFilters)}
          />
        </div>
      ),
      filterIcon: (filtered) => {
        return (
          <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? "#1890ff" : undefined }} />
        );
      },
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try out the following and see your console.log?

```
const [activeFilters, setActiveFilters]  = useState([]);

 const handleFilters = (selectedKeys) => { // no async
    
    const filter = [...activeFilters]
    console.log('filter', filter) // check that your array is populated before you're doing findIndex
    
    const index = filter.findIndex((array) => {
      console.log('array Key', array.key, 'equality', array.key === selectedKeys.key)
      return array.key === selectedKeys.key
    });
    console.log('index', index);
  (...)
}
```

It should be working fine and there are a couple of errors with your second approach, you can't really do `const filter = activeFilters`, cause then you're mutating the state directly, which is a no-no in React.

Please try out the logging I've suggested and see the output, you'll be able to catch the error I think.

Comment: I've try console.log everything , to undestand what is happening... and yes, exactly, I can't const filter = active Filters
console.log(filter) always output an empty array...
it's value never is updated

Comment: So calling this fn before setting the active filters I suppose, any help is needed?

Comment: I answered my own question, please check this out ?